# Power setting changes not being saved on suspend/reboot

Tags: power-management, nano

I've been trying to make changes to a few power saver setting files:

```
/sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save
/sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save_controller
```

by opening the files with:

```
sudo nano /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save
sudo nano /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save_controller
```

then changing the values and saving. The problem is that every time my laptop suspends or reboots, the settings are reverted to default values. The files seem to be ready-only so I'm unsure how they're reverting.

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1):

I believe a more appropriate way to do this is to create a file:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/snd_hda_intel.conf
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit. Add the parameter values:

```
options snd_hda_intel power_save=XX power_save_controller=YY
```

Where XX and YY are the desired values.

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor. Reboot.

Comment: I attempted this but when I inputted the values 100 for power_save and N for power_save_controller, the settings were reverted again after a reboot. I verified that the conf file exists and has the appropriate parameters before and after the reboot.